# Redirect with success or error message without using sessions

Tags: laravel

How can i redirect with success or error message without using sessions in laravel

Currently I am using the following code for redirect :

```
return redirect('dashboard')->with('status', 'Profile updated!');
```

But this code Need session to display the success message.

Comment: If you don't want to use session you would prabobly need to create two custom pages for each success and error

Comment: How are you displaying 'status' on blade?

Comment: Why don't you want to use session? You can pass via get request ```return redirect('dashboard?status=Profile+updated!');```

Answer (score 1):

You can set another variable status type along with the status like below,

```
return redirect('dashboard')->with(['status'=>'Profile updated!','status_type'=>'success']);
```

And in your dashboard blade file use

```
@if(isset($status))
    <p class="alert alert-{{ $status_type }}" >{{ $status }}</p>
@endif
```

Comment: dont work saddly

Comment: @LuisAlfredoSerranoDíaz  In which version of Laravel you are trying this?

Comment: Laravel 8 i had to use a $_GET to capture the data